# Meaning of Maclaurin expansion of $e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, recreational-mathematics, eulers-number-e

I was wondering if there is an interpretation or specific meaning to the series expansion of $e$.

$$ e = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} + \frac{1}{5!} + \cdots $$

Do the factorials in the denominator have something to do with the compound interest formula or the limit definition of $e$?

Additionally, I would really appreciate it if you provided me with something fun and curious that has to do with $e$.

Thanks!

Comment: To properly answer your question, we must first ask you how you have $e$ *defined*.  There are many different ways to define $e$, one of which is to *define* it as $\text{exp}(1)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 1/k!$ in which case there is nothing more to note.

Comment: Given $f(x)$, the general formula for the Maclaurin series at $1$ is 
$$f(1)= \frac{f(0)}{0!} + \frac{f'(0)}{1!} + \frac{f''(0)}{2!} + \frac{f^{(3)}(0)}{3!} + \dots + \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} + \cdots $$
The factorials are always there. They have nothing to do with $e$.

Comment: The limit definition of $e$, which arises in the study of compound interest, is $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$.  The binomial series for $(1+1/n)^n$ is $1+1+\frac {n(n-1)}{2!n^2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!n^3}+... $ Does that help?

Comment: The most fun thing having to do with $e$ is $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes! That helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit definition of $e,$ which arises in the study of compound interest, is

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n.$$

The [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is $$1 +   n   \frac 1 n  + \frac {n(n-1)}{2!}\biggl(\frac 1n\biggr)^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\biggl(\frac 1 n\biggr)^3+...;$$

I think you could see from that where the factorials come from.

I think most mathematicians would agree with @Gerry Myerson's comment that the most beautiful

equation involving $e$ is [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity):

$$e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0,$$ but here's another fun fact about Euler's number, involving the factorial function:

$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n {\sqrt[n]{n!}}.$$

Comment: I hope it was okay to adjust the size of the parentheses.

Comment: @robjohn:  Sure, thanks